# TypeScript errors in node_modules during Vite wagmi rainbowkit build

Tags: typescript, vite, wagmi

I'm experiencing several TypeScript compilation errors during my Vite build process. The errors seem to originate from the type declarations in my node_modules.

Here are some of the errors:

```
node_modules/@rainbow-me/rainbowkit/dist/wallets/connectorsForWallets.d.ts:2:78 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Connector'.

2 export declare const connectorsForWallets: (walletList: WalletList) => () => Connector[];
                                                                              

node_modules/@web3modal/core/dist/_types/src/controllers/ClientCtrl.d.ts:5:22 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@web3modal/ethereum' or its corresponding type declarations.

5     client(): import("@web3modal/ethereum").EthereumClient;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/viem/dist/types/clients/transports/webSocket.d.ts:2:15 - error TS2595: 'WebSocket' can only be imported by using a default import.

2 import type { WebSocket } from 'isomorphic-ws';
```

My tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es2015",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

I have already made sure to import all necessary dependencies, and yet the errors persist. Is there a way to build the project without ignoring library checks?